# ssh: connect to host X.X.X.X port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, time, ssh, connection, out

I'm running a linux based (centos 6.5) VPS. I had no problem since yesterday that everything was fine . I was editing **Iptables** rules , trying to reject and allow some services and ports but suddenly I got disconnected from VPS and could not connect anymore. I Googled a lot and read many topics regarding this problem but none of them helped me.

I tried:

- Reinstalling sshserver and client
- Flushing Iptables, saving it and then restarting it
- Changing the port for ssh using from /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to sth
  else and then allowing this new port from iptables

but I still have the problem.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Editing IPTables (native Linux firewall) make the possibility to cut/block your socket connections because you are managing a realtime firewall. If you blocked port TCP/22, you are lost. You need connect via KVM to the server if you can or contact with the VPS admin to unlock this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have access to the ssh via VNC, but I don't know what KVM is.

Comment: Ok, thus verify your IPTables rules are not wrong.

Comment: I have Flushed the iptables permanently but again the problem exists.

Comment: Put this rule : iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Comment: No problem Hamed, I put the solution in the answer side. Don't forget to upvote the answer if I solved your question ;)

Comment: Thanks Turrican I up voted your answer but I don't have enough reputation to take effect and display it publicly. it said once I have enough reputation it will take effect.... Thanks again...

Comment: I know Hamed. No problem to this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we commented :

Put this rule : iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT